# Add Red Text in Tooptip?

Tags: python, scripting

is it possible to add a custom red text in tooltip ?

here is an example:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently this feature is not available through the Python API, only for operators implemented in C.

The operator in your screenshot `select_ungrouped()` is implemented in [`source\blender\editors\mesh\editmesh_select.c`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/mesh/editmesh_select.c)

Operators can use a poll function to check whether they can be executed in the current context. This functionality for `select_ungrouped()` is implemented in `edbm_select_ungrouped_poll()`. In this function the message in red is set through:

```
CTX_wm_operator_poll_msg_set(C, "Must be in vertex selection mode");
```

[image: Red text in menu]

If a message is set through this function and the operator is disabled because poll returns false, it will be displayed beneath the operator's description as a tooltip in the UI. This behavior is implemented in [`source\blender\editors\interface\interface_region_tooltip.c`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/interface/interface_region_tooltip.c)

The documentation mentions this feature in the [Gotchas page](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_gotcha.html#why-does-an-operator-s-poll-fail).

> Blender does have the functionality for poll functions to describe why they fail, but its currently not used much, if you’re interested to help improve our API feel free to add calls to `CTX_wm_operator_poll_msg_set` where its not obvious why poll fails.